# How to send mail with java mail by using Gmail SMTP with OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, smtp, jakarta-mail, google-oauth

I read the link below but I couldn't send mail with OAuth2 authentication mechanism. Can anyone give me an example about this ?

Without this authentication user have to enable less secure apps option from the gmail's security settings. But I don't want to push user to do that. That's why I need this authentication mechanism.

link: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2

Comment: Please provide more details on what you tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen.  "I read the link" isn't enough to know if you followed the instructions correctly.

Comment: Hi Bill,
Actually problem is that I cannot take "oauth2_access_token". In my program user writes his own e-mail address and password then he will be able to send e-mail. How can i get token for him ?

Comment: If you're logging into a user's account, the user needs to set up the account to allow your program to log in, by enabling less secure apps, or your application needs to follow the procedure described in the [Google OAuth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?csw=1) depending on the type of application you're developing.  The user will need to login to Google and then authorize your application to access the user's email.

Answer (score 5):

Given below is the working code how to send emails using OAuth2 in a web project using Spring.

**Important :**

- First create project at [Google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), after that when creating credentials at Google console  remember to set
  application type to other.
- Use [oauth2.py](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/python/oauth2.py) get access token and other required values needed for the
  code. File itself has instructions on how to use it, to get required values.

**spring-email.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- email configuration -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Use SMTP transport protocol -->
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <!-- GMail requires OAuth to not be considered "low-security" -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms">XOAUTH2</prop>
                <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="message" class="com.upriverbank.model.Message">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**OAuthMail.java**

```
package com.abc.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class OAuthMail {


    // For using Oauth2

    private static String TOKEN_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    // Not a best practice to store client id, secret and token in source
    // must be stored in a file.
    private String oauthClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    private String oauthSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static String accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" +
                                            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private long tokenExpires = 1458168133864L;

    // getters and setters

    public static String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public static void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        accessToken = accessToken;
    }


    /*
    Renew access token if expired
     */
    public void renewToken(){

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() > tokenExpires) {

            try
            {
                String request = "client_id="+ URLEncoder.encode(oauthClientId, "UTF-8")
                        +"&client_secret="+URLEncoder.encode(oauthSecret, "UTF-8")
                        +"&refresh_token="+URLEncoder.encode(refreshToken, "UTF-8")
                        +"&grant_type=refresh_token";
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(TOKEN_URL).openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.print(request);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                conn.connect();

                try
                {

                    HashMap<String,Object> result;
                    result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(conn.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {});
                    accessToken = (String) result.get("access_token");
                    tokenExpires = System.currentTimeMillis()+(((Number)result.get("expires_in")).intValue()*1000);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    System.out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Message.java**

```
package com.abc.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.upriverbank.security.OAuthMail;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Message {


    public static final String PORT = "465";
    private static final String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    private String name;
    private String customerID;
    private String email;
    private int queryType;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String rStatus;
    private String query;
    private Byte isRead;
    private int customerId;
    private String password;
    private static final String BANK_SUPPORT_EMAIL = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";


    public static String getBankSupportEmail() {
        return BANK_SUPPORT_EMAIL;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getrStatus() {
        return rStatus;
    }

    public void setrStatus(String rStatus) {
        this.rStatus = rStatus;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public Byte getIsRead() {
        return isRead;
    }

    public void setIsRead(Byte isRead) {
        this.isRead = isRead;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(String customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getQueryType() {
        return queryType;
    }

    public void setQueryType(int queryType) {
        this.queryType = queryType;
    }




    public void viewMessage() {

    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }



   /*
      Sending an email according to provided parameters
      (sender, receiver, subject, content)
   */
    public void sendMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String msg) {


        ((JavaMailSenderImpl)this.mailSender).setPassword(OAuthMail.getAccessToken());

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);

        // sending email

        mailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

**MessageTest.java**

```
package com.abc.model;

import com.abc.support.spring.SpringUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    class MessageTest {

        @Test
        void sendMessage() {

            Message mm = (Message) SpringUtil.customBeanFactory("message");
            mm.sendMessage("xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                    "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                    "Testing email",
                    "This is a testing email");
        }

    }
```